# Java. Ответ с клавиатуры, от которого зависят дальнейшие действия

Tags: java, операторы, switch, scanner

Изучаю Java, но знаю еще недостаточно глубоко. Появилась нужда в таком коде - игра 21.

Юзер получил 2 карты на руки и его спрашивают - готовы продолжить? Если он вводит `Y` - то третий раз срабатывает метод, дающий карту, если `N` - срабатывает метод выхода, и переход хода к крупье.

Я пытаюсь "натянуть" это все на

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

и что-то типа

```
if (scanner.equals(Y)) 
{
    то то и то то
}
else 
{
    что то другое
}
```

Еще пытался засунуть два варианта ответа в switch, но что-то ничего не получается.

Направьте пожалуйста на путь истинный :)

Comment: можно использовать бесконечный цикл с заданный условием выхода.

Comment: Получилось вот так:
 if (a.equals(y)) {
            firstCard.lookCard();
        }
        if (a.equals(n)) {
            System.out.println("До свидания");
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(a, y) && !Objects.equals(a, n)) {
            System.out.println("Неправильный вариант");
            System.exit(0);
        }
Но я вот больше чем уверен что это порнография а не код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

boolean b = true;
while (b) {
    String string = in.next().toLowerCase();
    switch (string) {
        case "y":
            // дать карту
            break;
        case "n":
            // сделать что то другое;
            b = false;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Вы ввели неверное значение.");
    }
}
```